# To find Cassandra disk space usage

Tags: cassandra

I am using Jconsole for monitoring Cassandra. I can get value like how much load each keyspace is having.
I want to find out disk space usage for each node in a cluster by remotely.
Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

A shell script can do the trick

```
for i in node1_ip node2_ip ... nodeN_ip
do
ssh user@$i "du -sh /var/lib/cassandra/data" >> /tmp/disk_usage.txt
done
```

Replace `/var/lib/cassandra/data` if your data folder is put somewhere else

Comment: Thank you it's really useful but how to this for Windows platform?

Comment: But what if my Cassandra is installed on windows platform?

Comment: Humm, if using Windows Seven or more, you can look at PowerShell to find if there is an equivalent for the command **du -sh** : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx